# Clicking on local links to named anchors (for headings) in HTML blob?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this HTML with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Test open</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <button type="button" id="btn-open-tab">Open html in new tab</button>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openNewTabAsHtml(text) {
    const blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/html'});
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    setTimeout(() => window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url), 100);
  }

  let my_html_str = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Test opened</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Click <a href="#1-testing">here</a></p>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <h2 id="1-testing">1. Testing</h2>
  <p>Testing stuff here...</p>
  </body>
</html>
  `;

  let btn_open_tab = document.getElementById("btn-open-tab");
  btn_open_tab.onclick = function(elem) {
    openNewTabAsHtml(my_html_str);
  };
  </script>
</html>
```

If I run this in Firefox 115, and click on "Open html in new tab", I get a new tab opened; if I click on the resulting "Click here", I'm taken to the heading - as expected.

However, if here I scroll up, and then "Click here" again, then nothing happens!

Is this expected browser behavior, or a bug? Regardless, can I somehow have local links to named heading anchors work in a HTML blob every time?

Comment: Thanks @Konrad - it seems that it does; I do not recall it being an issue earlier, so I thought it was specifically related to blob.